# Custom object listing in Django admin

Tags: python, django

I'm new at Django and I'm creating a small app that has some really simple models but uses custom users. Now I wish to customize the object listing in the administration for some users. What I wish to do is customize the object listing in
`myserver/admin/myapp/myobject` but I haven't found which should I extend to do so. I'd be thank to know where should I look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take a thorough look through the Django admin documentation.  They do a pretty good job at explaining how to customize the list display.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/

I would focus on learning the following,
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display
This will alter the fields being shown for each row in the list.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter
This will allow you to filter your data which is shown within the list.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.search_fields
This will allow you to add a search box which will let you search against the objects within the list.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. I've just realized that I have to change my approach. I'll separate staff from non staff users and implement the site as it should be.